# What will be the code for navigating from button on UITableviewCell to other view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton

Here is my table view,

[image]

Initially, it looks like this, when I click on in this cell then it will expand

[image]

**My Question**: I added a button to UITableviewCell and given action for it. When I click on attachment button then It has to navigate to next view. I tried below code but it works for UIViewcontroller, not for UITableViewCell.

```
AttachmentView *attach=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"attachViewId"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:attach animated:YES];
```

How to achieve this?

here is my ConversationTableViewCell.h file,

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface ConversationTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *profilePicView;

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *clientNameLabel;

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *internalNoteLabel;

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timeStampLabel;

    -(void)setUserProfileimage:(NSString*)imageUrl;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view1;

    - (IBAction)clickedOnAttachment:(id)sender;
```

and this is ConversationTableViewCell.m file code,

```
 #import "HexColors.h"
    #import "ConversationTableViewCell.h"
    #import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
    #import "AttachmentViewController.h"

    @implementation ConversationTableViewCell

    - (void)awakeFromNib {
        [super awakeFromNib];

    }

    - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
        [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

      }

    -(void)setUserProfileimage:(NSString*)imageUrl
    {
       // self.profilePicView.layer.borderWidth=1.25f;
        self.profilePicView.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor hx_colorWithHexRGBAString:@"#0288D1"] CGColor];
        [self.profilePicView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]
                               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default_pic.png"]];

    }

    - (IBAction)clickedOnAttachment:(id)sender {

     //   NSLog(@"CLciked...!");

        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                                 bundle: nil];

        AttachmentViewController * attach=[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"attachId"];

        [self.navigation];
    }
    @end
```

This is view controller code,

```
// this is ConversationTableViewCell view controllers .m file

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    ConversationTableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ConvTableViewCell"];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ConversationTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    NSDictionary *finaldic=[mutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



@try{


    attachmentArray=[finaldic objectForKey:@"attach"];

    if ([attachmentArray count] != 0){

        NSIndexPath *path;
        NSDictionary *attachDictionary=[attachmentArray objectAtIndex:path.row];
        //   NSLog(@"Attchment Dict is: %@",attachDictionary);

        NSString *numStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [attachDictionary objectForKey:@"file"]];
            }else
    {
        NSLog(@"EMpty aaray");
    }



    cell.timeStampLabel.text=[utils getLocalDateTimeFromUTC:[finaldic objectForKey:@"created_at"]];


    NSString *body= [finaldic objectForKey:@"body"]; 
    NSRange range = [body rangeOfString:@"<body"];

    if(range.location != NSNotFound) {
        // Adjust style for mobile
        float inset = 40;
        NSString *style = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<style>div {max-width: %fpx;}</style>", self.view.bounds.size.width - inset];
        body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", [body substringToIndex:range.location], style, [body substringFromIndex:range.location]];
    }
    cell.webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [cell.webView loadHTMLString:body baseURL:nil];



   //NSString *system= @"System";
   NSString *fName=[finaldic objectForKey:@"first_name"];
   NSString *lName=[finaldic objectForKey:@"last_name"];
   NSString *userName=[finaldic objectForKey:@"user_name"];

   [Utils isEmpty:fName];
   [Utils isEmpty:lName];
   [Utils isEmpty:userName];



     if  ([Utils isEmpty:fName] && [Utils isEmpty:lName]){
         if(![Utils isEmpty:userName]){
        userName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[finaldic objectForKey:@"user_name"]];
             cell.clientNameLabel.text=userName;
         }else cell.clientNameLabel.text=@"System";
    }
    else if ((![Utils isEmpty:fName] || ![Utils isEmpty:lName]) || (![Utils isEmpty:fName] && ![Utils isEmpty:lName]))
    {
       NSString * fName12=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",fName,lName];

        cell.clientNameLabel.text=fName12;

    }

// prifile image
        if([[finaldic objectForKey:@"profile_pic"] hasSuffix:@"system.png"] || [[finaldic objectForKey:@"profile_pic"] hasSuffix:@".jpg"] || [[finaldic objectForKey:@"profile_pic"] hasSuffix:@".jpeg"] || [[finaldic objectForKey:@"profile_pic"] hasSuffix:@".png"] )
        {
            [cell setUserProfileimage:[finaldic objectForKey:@"profile_pic"]];
        }
         else if(![Utils isEmpty:fName])
        {
            [cell.profilePicView setImageWithString:fName color:nil ];
        }
       else
       {
           [cell.profilePicView setImageWithString:userName color:nil ];
       }


}@catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        [utils showAlertWithMessage:exception.name sendViewController:self];
        NSLog( @"Name: %@", exception.name);
        NSLog( @"Reason: %@", exception.reason );
       // return;
    }
    @finally
    {
        NSLog( @" I am in cellForROwAtIndexPath method in Conversation ViewController" );

    }


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Have you written `[self.navigationController attach animated:YES];` or `[self.navigationController pushViewController: attach animated:YES];`

Comment: sorry, I forgot. pushViewController was not copied in question. Yes, I tried it is giving an error that self.view or self.navigationController is not found on ConversationTableViewCell.

Comment: Have you written that code inside your custom cell subclass?

Comment: yes, I did already

Comment: Please post your `cellforrowatindexpath` code.

Comment: You can't push from your `UITableViewCell` subclass. There are two ways to achieve this. One is you need to write a custom delegate method from your cell subclass to your view controller and write your code for oushing view controller there or you can add a target method of your `button` programmatically in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, then you can add your code to push view controller inside that target method. If you post your `ViewController` class code, I can show you how you can achieve that. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.navigationController` is not available in `ConversationTableViewCell` class.

In order to push a new instance of `UIViewController` on click of cell/ a button on a cell, you should use `Delegation design pattern`.

Example -

```
//ConversationTableViewCell.h

@protocol ConversationTableViewCellDelegate;

@interface ConversationTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (assign, nonatomic) id < ConversationTableViewCellDelegate > delegate;

@end

@protocol ConversationTableViewCellDelegate <NSObject>

@optional

- (void)buttonTouchedForCell:(ConversationTableViewCell *)cell;

@end

//ConversationTableViewCell.m
@implementation ConversationTableViewCell

@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

- (IBAction)clickedOnAttachment:(id)sender {
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(buttonTouchedForCell:)])
        [self.delegate buttonTouchedForCell:self];
    }
@end


@interface YourController : UIViewController <ConversationTableViewCellDelegate>

@end

@implementation YourController

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 ConversationTableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ConvTableViewCell"];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
           NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ConversationTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
           cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        [cell setDelegate:self];

        // cell related code

        return cell;
    }

    - (void) buttonTouchedForCell:(ConversationTableViewCell *)cell {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

        AttachmentView *attach=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"attachViewId"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:attach animated:YES];
    }

@end
```

Comment: let me check this @sanjay

Comment: sure @Nikita, all the best !